# why make command is not working in solaris 11 server?

Tags: unix, package, solaris

I am trying to build a package in my solaris 11 server. I am using 'make'command for that and not able to build package

have already tried below commands:-
1)make
2)sudo make
3)make package

The error I am getting

bash-4.4$ make

cc   -c  timeout.c

sh: cc: not found

*** Error code 127

make: Fatal error: Command failed for target `timeout.o'

bash-4.4$ sudo make

cc   -c  timeout.c

sh: cc: not found

*** Error code 127

make: Fatal error: Command failed for target `timeout.o'

bash-4.4$ ^C
bash-4.4$ ^C
bash-4.4$

Answer (score 1):

`sh: cc: not found` means you do not have a program named cc found in your `$PATH`, so it can't figure out what C compiler you want it to run.

If you've installed the Oracle Developer Studio compilers, then you need to add the path to them to your `$PATH` environment variable.

If you're using gcc instead, you probably need to run `make CC=gcc` to set the CC variable to the name of the compiler you want to use.

Comment: In which directory do i need to run make CC=gcc, any specific path or I can execute this command from any directory.

Comment: In the directory you tried to run the `make` command shown above - this does not change the configuration of your server, but is an added argument to the make command you tried to run to tell it to use a different compiler for this operation.